# Convert Hyperlinks to HTML code in Excel

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink, vba

I have a column of hyperlinks in an Excel file and I want to convert them to their respective HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Link Name</a>
```

I found ways to extract the link only (as text), but I need the whole HTML code as text to replace the hyperlink in the cell.

[image]

I've searched and searched but no one needed this answer, I guess. Can someone help?

Comment: your link looks perfect! Please specify clearly what you have and what the result should look like.

Comment: thanks for replyin, I added a screenshot to make it clear. I want to replace the hyperlink with its HTML code (in the Excel cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a fairly straightforward method to yank the `.Address` and optional `.SubAddress` from the [Hyperlinks collection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839966.aspx). The `.TextToDisplay` property is simply the value or text of the cell.

```
Sub html_anchors()
    Dim a As Range, u As String, l As String
    Dim sANCHOR As String: sANCHOR = "<a href=""%U%"">%L%</a>"

    For Each a In Selection
        With a
            If CBool(.Hyperlinks.Count) Then
                l = .Text
                u = .Hyperlinks(1).Address
                If Right(u, 1) = Chr(47) Then u = Left(u, Len(u) - 1)
                .Hyperlinks(1).Delete
                .Value = Replace(Replace(sANCHOR, "%U%", u), "%L%", l)
            End If
        End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

Select all of the cells you want to process and run the routine. If any cell in your selection does not contain a hyperlink, it will be ignored.

Comment: Awesome, Jeeped, thanks a lot!
It's deffinitely not straightforward for me :)

Comment: One small problem - the code adds a trailing forward slash at the end of the URL, and my pdf files now give a 404 error because of it:

a href="http:/www.example.com/file_2006.pdf/"

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Yep. I was worried that concatenating the address and subaddress was going to produce a double forward slash but didn't stop to think that `http://` NEEDS a double forward slah. Give me a sec...

Comment: hey, Jeeped, have you managed to fix the issue? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The subaddress was doing nothing for your purposes and the variations of possible subaddress types were giving me conniptions so I removed them altogether. I may revisit this a little further down the road if I can manage to collect a reasonably complete assortment of subaddress styles but for now, this should serve your purposes.

Comment: It serves my purposes just fine. Let me say thank you again for your effort!